# Sie setzten sich auf die Schaukel(n)

Tags: grammatical-number, writing

Ich verstehe, dass *Schaukeln* der Plural von *Schaukel* ist. Allerdings empfinde ich ein Gestell, an dem mehrere Schaukeln hängen, als Schaukel, nicht als Schaukeln. Nach meinem Empfinden ist dieses Spielgerät *eine Schaukel:*

[image]

Entsprechend würde ich sagen, dass diese Kinder *auf der Schaukel* sitzen (nicht *auf den Schaukeln*):

[image]

Wenn ich nun aber in einem Text beschreiben möchte, dass zwei Kinder sich in einem solchen Spielgerät jeweils auf ihren eigenen Schaukelsitz setzen, dann fühlen sich für mich die beiden folgenden Sätze unpassend an:

> 1. Hannah und Mia gingen in den Garten und setzten sich auf die Schaukel.
> 2. Hannah und Mia gingen in den Garten und setzten sich auf die Schaukeln.

Der erste Satz scheint mir zu suggerieren, dass sich beide Kinder zusammen auf **eine einzige Schaukel** setzen, die entweder breit genug für zwei Personen ist, oder ein Mädchen setzt sich auf den Schoß der anderen. Der zweite Satz dagegen hört sich einfach nur merkwürdig für mich an. Google findet zwar Beispiele für den Plural, aber mein Sprachgefühl sagt, dass der Plural hier ungebräuchlich ist.

Wie drückt man den Sinn, dass zwei Personen sich auf zwei Schaukeln setzen, richtig aus (ohne das umständlich zu beschreiben)?

Comment: "Der zweite Satz dagegen hört sich einfach nur merkwürdig für mich an." Wahrscheinlich nur weil das Verb "schaukeln" genauso klingt. Außerdem stimme ich nicht mit der Auffassung überein, dass das ganze Gestell eine Schaukel ist. Manche Gestelle haben außer den Schaukeln auch noch ein paar Kletterstangen oder eine Leiter. Auf dem Bild oben sieht man also 2 Schaukeln an einem Gestell.

Comment: So etwas wird gerne auch als Doppelschaukel bezeichnet. Was den Plural schon mit sich bringt. Dementsprechend denke ich, dass der Ansatz der Frage schon verkehrt ist. Nicht zu vergessen, dass es noch andere Arten von Schaukeln gibt wie in [diesem Link](https://www.mytoys.de/kettler-doppelschaukel-3-4412828.html). Da können tatsächlich 2 Kinder auf einer sitzen. Würde man 2 Reifen mit Seil an einem Ast hängen wären das ja auch 2 Schaukeln statt 1. Im Endeffekt sollte der Kontext immer Klarheit bringen. Wurde die Schaukel vorher entsprechend beschrieben ist immer klar, was gemeint ist.

Answer (score 1):

> Hannah und Mia gingen in den Garten und setzten sich (*jede*) auf eine Schaukel.

Comment: Eben das empfinde ich als umständlich. So etwas würde niemand sagen, und kein Autor schreiben. Weil mit dem "jeweils" die Umstände des Sitzens mehr betont werden, als ihnen zukommt. Das ist als würdest du schreiben: "Paul und Johanna gingen ins Restaurant und setzten sich jeweils auf einen eigenen Stuhl." Ja, wie denn auch sonst? Das wirkt, als wolltest du da einen Witz machen.

Comment: "Paul und Johanna gingen ins Restaurant und setzten sich _jeder_ auf einen Stuhl." Dass es der _eigene Stuhl_ ist, und nicht der des jeweils anderen, muss nicht extra gesagt werden.

Answer (score 1):

Ein Schaukelgerüst mit zwei einzelnen Schaukeln nennt sich

> Doppelschaukel

was, denke ich, ausreichend selbsterklärend ist.

> Hannah und Mia gingen in den Garten und setzten sich auf die Doppelschaukel.

ist zwar ein *häßlicher* Satz, aber kein Leser würde annehmen, dass Hannah und Mia sich gemeinsam auf nur eine der beiden Schaukeln setzen.

Answer (score 1):

Plural ist sowohl grammatikalisch als auch inhaltlich möglich und ich empfinde das in keiner Weise als störend.

Um den hier bereits erläuterten Missverständnissen vorzubeugen muss man sogar den Plural verwenden. Das sieht man ganz gut, wenn man hier ein Possessivpronomen einführt (wie es Kinder gerne tun):

> Hannah und Mia gingen in den Garten und setzten sich auf ihre Schaukel.

Das geht grammatikalisch und klingt auch gut, aber es handelt sich dann eben strenggenommen nur um eine Schaukel, die den beiden eben gehört.

Eindeutiger ist:

> Hannah und Mia gingen in den Garten und setzten sich auf ihre Schaukel**n**.

Answer (score 0):

Der zweite Satz ist völlig korrekt.

> Hannah und Mia gingen in den Garten und setzten sich auf die Schaukeln.

Es macht hierbei keinen Unterschied ob die Schaukeln gemeinsam an einem Gestell oder an mehreren unterschiedlichen angebracht sind.

Im Übrigen würde ich das dargestellte Spielgerät selten als solches ansprechen und wenn dann als "das Schaukelgestänge" oder "das Schaukelgerüst", nie aber als "die Schaukel" denn die Schaukel besteht aus einem (oder mehren) flexiblen Teilen an die man sich unten dranhängen kann oder das unten etwas zum drauf setzen hat. Die Befestigung ist nicht Teil des Begriffs (für mich). Zum Beispiel würde ich, wenn ich eine Schaukel kaufen würde, nicht erwarten das ich eine Befestigung dazu bekomme.

Comment: Dem letzten Absatz würde ich nicht zustimmen. Es ist eben das Problem, dass eine Schaukel sowohl das "Schaukelgerüst" komplett als auch den einzelnen "Schaukelsitz" bezeichnet. Aber ansonsten hast du recht - der zweite Satz ist völlig korrekt, um den Sachverhalt zu beschreiben.

Answer (score -2):

> Hannah und Mia gingen in den Garten und setzten sich auf die nebeneinander
>
> - befindlichen
> - angeordneten
> - hängenden
>
> Schaukeln.

Comment: So eine gestelzte Formulierung findet man höchstens in einer Niederschrift, die ein Ermittlungsbeamter während eines Verhörs verfasst hat.

Comment: Diese Antwort bestätigt auch wieder, dass es sich um 2 Schaukeln handelt und nicht eine.

Comment: @Javatasse: Ja, es sind zwei. Schaukel laut [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schaukel): _»aus einem an zwei Seilen, Ketten o. Ä. waagerecht aufgehängten Brett o. Ä. bestehendes Spielgerät zum Schaukeln«_.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Bei "befindlichen" stimme ich dir da dazu, aber "angeordneten", und vor allem "hängenden" empfinde ich keineswegs als gestelzt.